Is there a way to pass an SSH key for both the bastion and the target using `ssh -J`?
I want a short-hand notation for:
ssh bar@<target> -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -oProxyCommand="ssh foo@<bastion> -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -W %h:%p"

If I just do -J I get:
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -J foo@<bastion> bar@<target>
foo@<bastion>: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535

Neither does duplicating -i as I've read in some posts:
ssh -J foo@<bastion> -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 bar@<target>

I'm currently running OpenSSH 8.9p1:
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.10, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022


The manual explicitly states:

Use ~/.ssh/config to specify configuration for jump hosts.

-i in the command line corresponds to IdentityFile in the config. This is the directive you should use. Example snippet:
Match Host <bastion> User foo
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
Match all

